# Super Reduced String

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, strings, programming-challenge

Online challenge on [Hacker Rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/reduced-string).

> #### Problem Statement
>
> Steve has a string, `S`, consisting of `n` lowercase English alphabetic >letters. In one operation, he can delete any pair of adjacent letters with same >value. For example, string `"aabcc"` would become either `"aab"` or `"bcc"` >after operation.
>
> Steve wants to reduce  as much as possible. To do this, he will repeat the >above operation as many times as it can be performed. Help Steve out by finding >and printing `S`'s non-reducible form!
>
> Note: If the final string is empty, print `Empty String`.
>
> #### Input Format
>
> A single string, `S`.
>
> #### Constraints
>
> \$1 ≤ n ≤ 100\$
>
> #### Output Format
>
> If the final string is empty, print Empty String; otherwise, print the final >non-reducible string.
>
> #### Sample Input
>
> `aaabccddd`
>
> #### Sample Output
>
> `abd`

---

#### Solution Code

```
public class Solution {
    private static String solve(String input) {
        int len = input.length();

        int i = 0;
        while (i < len - 1) {
            char current = input.charAt(i);
            char next = input.charAt(i+1);

            if (current == next) {
                input = input.substring(0, i) + input.substring(i+2);
                len = input.length();
                i = 0;
                continue;
            }
            i++;
        }
        if (input.length() == 0) {
            return "Empty String";
        }
        return input;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println(solve(s.next()));
    }
}
```

This is a brute-force solution, as I feel kind of confused when dealing with string algorithms. Hope for some good suggestions here.

Comment: What do you think is the theoretical speed of your algorithm?  Do you think it is \$O(n)\$, \$O(n \log n)\$, \$O(n^2)\$, \$O(n^3)\$, or other?  And what do you think the speed of the optimal solution is?

Comment: Hint: try to implement it using a `LinkedList` of characters instead of keeping `String`s. You should be able to prevent all the `substring()` calls.

Comment: @RobAu a working example please.

Comment: @JS1 my intuition says its O(n^2) since I am resetting position of i beginning after finding a duplicate pair.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Doc comments for public methods are indispensable.

I'd probably just use a *foreach*-loop and a DIY stack:

```
/** @return input stripped of all abutting identical characters */
static String solve(String input) {
    char []remains = new char[input.length()];
    int top = -1; // highest valid index

    for (char c: input.toCharArray())
        if (top < 0 || c != remains[top])
            remains[++top] = c;
        else
            --top;

    return top < 0 ? "Empty String"
        : new String(remains, 0, top+1);
}
```

Comment: A very clean solution indeed, what was you thought process?

Comment: @CodeYogi: unstructured - documented the purpose, coded "the stack approach" using a `StringBuilder`, switched to `char` array, revised variable names, copied to CR, re-defined `top` from _lowest invalid_ to _highest valid_, noticed I had to handle negative values of `top`, needed a CR user to point out that `0` was handled improperly (telling about my taking this seriously and (_not_) making step 2 _makeshift test scaffold_)…

Comment: I know there cannot be any rule but yes thinking like this helped me to solve another problem http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/151023/58341 is there some kind of pattern?

Comment: You can use `remains = input.toCharArray(); ... for (char c : remains)` to avoid the creation of a not required char array.

Comment: @Nevay: looks true - I'm hesitant to mangle an iterable being iterated, even if at indices not to be re-visited by iteration.

Answer (score 0):

IMHO your solution looks quite good. There would be a solution using *regular expressions* but I think your solution fits better the plan of your course...

---

The only thing I'd change is the `continue` within your `while` loop.

`continue` and `break` (within loops) are the "poor man's `goto`" and should be avoided since they harm readability of your code and make refactoring harder.

So instead of `continue` simply use `else` to skip `i++` when your condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

Two suggestions.  First, you are restarting your loop part-way through the string and resetting `i` to 0.  That means you are checking the first part of the string more than once.  For input like "abbccddeeff" you will be checking the "a" five times.  Instead, do a full pass with the loop and then do another full pass only if needed. Separating the loop logic into two loops seems clearer to me as well.

Second, since most of the work will be deleting characters from strings, I think that using a `StringBuilder` would help, specifically the `StringBuilder.delete(a, b)` method.

```
private static String solve(String input) {

    StringBuilder insb = new StringBuilder(input);

    boolean passNeeded = true;

    while (passNeeded) {

        passNeeded = false;

        // Do a single full pass.
        for (int i = 0; i < insb.length() - 1; ++i) {
            char current = insb.charAt(i);
            char next = insb.charAt(i+1);

            if (current == next) {
                insb = insb.delete(i, i+2);

                // Text has changed so another pass needed.
                passNeeded = true;
            }

        } // end for

    } // end while

    if (insb.length() == 0) {
        return "Empty String";
    }

    return insb.toString();

} // end solve();
```

Comment: (I'd probably use a new `StringBuilder` encountering the first double, and append parts to keep - if I didn't go regex in the first place.)

Comment: IMHO your algorithm is not different than mine, in my case I am restarting again only when there is a duplicate pair.

Comment: I do a full pass, finding all the immediate ("aa") duplicate pairs in the first pass.    You do partial passes, so your second and subsequent part-passes will find both immediate  and non-immediate ("**a**bb**a**") pairs.  I think that is a real difference.  I also find restarting the loop partway through makes it less easy to follow the logic.  YMMV.

Answer (score 0):

As it was mentioned in the question that you have to remove the repetitive elements inside
    the string, so firstly we will convert it to an Array, then we will compare it with every 
    next element of that Array, if it is equal to 0 then we have to splice the respective two 
    elements from Array and initially we will put a while condition so that it will iterate 
    through the loop every possible time.

```
var string = input.split('');
var result;

var Boolean = (1);

while (Boolean) {

    Boolean = (0);

    for (var i = 0; i <= string.length - 1; i++) {
        if(string[i] == string[i + 1]){
            string.splice(i, 2);


            result = string.join("");
            Boolean = (1);
            if(string.length == 0){
                result = "Empty String";
            }
        }
    }
}
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The formatting of your answer is broken - don't introduce every line of a non-code-block with four spaces. The question is tagged [tag:java] - please mention how the code you present is to be interpreted. There are spurious white lines in your code. The indentation is broken. there seem to be more closing than opening curly braces: did this run? Please don't add answers if not entirely different: edit!