# Alternating Characters

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, strings, programming-challenge

Online challenge on [Hacker Rank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/alternating-characters).

> Shashank likes strings in which consecutive characters are different.
>   For example, he likes ABABA, while he doesn't like ABAA. Given a
>   string containing characters `A` and `B` only, he wants to change it
>   into a string he likes. To do this, he is allowed to delete the
>   characters in the string.
>
> Your task is to find the minimum number of required deletions.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line contains an integer `T`, i.e. the number of test cases.
>   The next `T` lines contain a string each.
>
> **Output Format**
>
> For each test case, print the minimum number of deletions required.

```
public class Solution {
    private static int countChanges(String text) {
        char[] chars = new char[text.length()];
        int top = -1;

        int count = 0;
        for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
            if (top < 0 || c != chars[top]) {
                chars[++top] = c;
            } else {
                // top >= 0 or c == chars[top]
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int N = s.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.println(countChanges(s.next()));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### No need for stack

You've complicated things by constructing a stack for no reason.  All you need to remember is the last character.  For example:

```
private static int countChanges(String text) {
    char prev  = 0;
    int  count = 0;

    for (char c : text.toCharArray()) {
        if (c == prev) {
            count++;
        } else {
            prev = c;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

#### Misleading comment

This comment:

> ```
>             // top >= 0 or c == chars[top]
> ```

should read:

```
            // top >= 0 and c == chars[top]
```